# I am not able to get Navigation Bar using JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode6, xcode7, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Problem in getting Navigation Bar using JSQMessagesViewController, I have tried getting Navigation Bar in my project, but failed to get it. Please let me know what the methods need to be added to get it.

```
#import "JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout.h"
#import "JSQMessages.h"
#import "JSQPhotoMediaItem.h"
#import "JSQLocationMediaItem.h"
#import "JSQVideoMediaItem.h"
#import "JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker.h"
#import "JSQMessagesAvatarImage.h"
#import "JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.h"
#import "JSQMessagesBubbleImage.h"
#import "JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory.h"
#import "UIImage+JSQMessages.h"
#import "Chat.h"

@interface ChatpageViewController : JSQMessagesViewController
{
NSMutableArray * fularray;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSDictionary * receivedict;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mobile;

@property (strong, nonatomic) JSQMessagesBubbleImage *outgoingBubbleImageData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) JSQMessagesBubbleImage *incomingBubbleImageData;

@end

#import "ChatpageViewController.h"
@interface ChatpageViewController ()
@end
@implementation ChatpageViewController
@synthesize receivedict,name,mobile;

//-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
//{
//

// // self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = YES;
//}

    (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    fularray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",receivedict);
    name.text = [receivedict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    mobile.text =[receivedict objectForKey:@"Mobile"];

    JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleFactory = [[JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory alloc] init];

    self.outgoingBubbleImageData = [bubbleFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor]];
    self.incomingBubbleImageData = [bubbleFactory incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleLightGrayColor]];

    }

    (id)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    JSQMessage *message = [fularray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    if ([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
    return self.outgoingBubbleImageData;
    }

    return self.incomingBubbleImageData;
    }

    (id)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory avatarImageWithUserInitials:@"JL" backgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor] textColor:[UIColor whiteColor] font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0] diameter:30.0];
    }

    (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [fularray count];
    }

    (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
    }

    (id)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return fularray[indexPath.row];
    }

    (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    (NSString *)senderId
    {
    return [receivedict objectForKey:@"Mobile"];
    }

    (NSString *)senderDisplayName
    {

    return [receivedict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    }

    (NSDate *)date
    {
    return 18/03/2016;
    }

    (void)didPressSendButton:(UIButton *)button withMessageText:(NSString *)text senderId:(NSString *)senderId senderDisplayName:(NSString *)senderDisplayName date:(NSDate *)date
    {

    [JSQSystemSoundPlayer jsq_playMessageSentSound];

    JSQMessage *message = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:senderId
    senderDisplayName:senderDisplayName
    date:date
    text:text];

    [fularray addObject:message];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self finishSendingMessageAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",message);
    }
```

Myproject is saved in the link :https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozih8ko9836fmb2/chatapp.zip?dl=0

Comment: have u solved ur problem. i could not get ur dropbox sample code. attach sample and let me know.

Comment: Hi, yes Imran, I solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Goto MainStoryboard->select your Controller-> in menu choose Editor-> Embed in -> Navigation Controller

Comment: Tried not getting,

In the demo app I think they use the bellow code,
I did not understand could some one tell me what the method we need to use to get navigation

DemoMessagesViewController *vc = [DemoMessagesViewController messagesViewController];
                vc.delegateModal = self;
                UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
                [self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 1):

Change in JSQMessagesViewController.m file in **-(void)jsq_updateCollectionViewInsets**

[self jsq_setCollectionViewInsetsTopValue:self.topContentAdditionalInset + 64 bottomValue:CGRectGetMaxY(self.collectionView.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(self.inputToolbar.frame)];